# How to fix item next to content in a grid so that it always remains in view

Tags: css, css-position, css-grid

I have a simple grid where the left pane acts as the table of contents and the right pane is the content. How do I get the content in the left pane to stay where it is (fixed?) while the user scrolls through the content, so that it is always in view. Here is a js fiddle illustrating the problem and my code is below as well: https://jsfiddle.net/ma60fxvk/

```
<div id = 'grid'>
 <div id = "column-1">
 Table of contents
 (How do I get this to stay in view while the user scrolls down to read the content in #column-2?)
 </div>
  <div id = "column-1">
 <!-- lot of content here -->
 </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can have this

```
#grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}

#grid div:first-child {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  top: 0;
}

#grid div:last-child {
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Since `position: fixed` is putting element above everything you need to give it fixed width and push scrollable content to the right for the size of fixed content.

With this you will achive desired effect.

Learn more about positioning [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `position:sticky` but

you will need the second column to span 2 rows, else , both column will be scrolling up together.

`id` can be used only once per document, use `class` instead.

example with spanning and background-color to see where both boxes stand.

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}

.column-1 {
  grid-row: span 2;
  background: lightblue;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  grid-row: span 1;
}
```

```html
<div id='grid'>
  <div class="column-1 sticky">
    Table of contents (How do I get this to stay in view while the user scrolls down to read the content in #column-2?)

  </div>
  <div class="column-1">
    Super long content Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, voluptate, id. Reprehenderit quae tempora totam, sed ipsam at. Doloremque quae expedita dolor earum alias consequuntur, quisquam ipsum et itaque doloribus!Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla laudantium iusto, mollitia ut obcaecati omnis ullam enim natus. Optio commodi labore rerum possimus nesciunt, neque soluta, perferendis aliquam quia amet!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, voluptate, id. Reprehenderit quae tempora totam, sed ipsam at. Doloremque quae expedita dolor earum alias consequuntur, quisquam ipsum et itaque doloribus!Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla laudantium iusto, mollitia ut obcaecati omnis ullam enim natus. Optio commodi labore rerum possimus nesciunt, neque soluta, perferendis aliquam quia amet!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Optio ea possimus adipisci molestias, e. Optio ea possimus adipisci molestias, excepturi fuga, dolore eius quibusdam ab natus in obcaecati, a quis. Harum nulla perferendis ipsam quidem, modi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Omnis eius recusandae, facere eaque veniam earum dolores accusamus atque sequi asperiores laboriosam aperiam eos reprehenderit moLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, voluptate, id. Reprehenderit quae tempora
    totam, sed ipsam at. Doloremque quae expedita dolor earum alias consequuntur, quisquam ipsum et itaque doloribus!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla laudantium iusto, mollitia ut obcaecati omnis ullam enim natus. Optio
    commodi labore rerum possimus nesciunt, neque soluta, perferendis aliquam quia amet!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio ea possimus adipisci molestias, ellitia qui id veritatis quisquam animi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla saepe, consequuntur quidem iste, placeat vero quasi laborum ab voluptatibus repellendus reprehenderit itaque non quae quia, sed pariatur doloribus minus quo.
  </div>
</div>
```

margin-bottom works too, and still background-color to see where both boxes stand.

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}

.column-1 {
  background: lightblue;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  margin-bottom: auto
}
```

```html
<div id='grid'>
  <div class="column-1 sticky">
    Table of contents (How do I get this to stay in view while the user scrolls down to read the content in #column-2?)

  </div>
  <div class="column-1">
    Super long content Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, voluptate, id. Reprehenderit quae tempora totam, sed ipsam at. Doloremque quae expedita dolor earum alias consequuntur, quisquam ipsum et itaque doloribus!Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla laudantium iusto, mollitia ut obcaecati omnis ullam enim natus. Optio commodi labore rerum possimus nesciunt, neque soluta, perferendis aliquam quia amet!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, voluptate, id. Reprehenderit quae tempora totam, sed ipsam at. Doloremque quae expedita dolor earum alias consequuntur, quisquam ipsum et itaque doloribus!Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla laudantium iusto, mollitia ut obcaecati omnis ullam enim natus. Optio commodi labore rerum possimus nesciunt, neque soluta, perferendis aliquam quia amet!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Optio ea possimus adipisci molestias, e. Optio ea possimus adipisci molestias, excepturi fuga, dolore eius quibusdam ab natus in obcaecati, a quis. Harum nulla perferendis ipsam quidem, modi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Omnis eius recusandae, facere eaque veniam earum dolores accusamus atque sequi asperiores laboriosam aperiam eos reprehenderit moLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, voluptate, id. Reprehenderit quae tempora
    totam, sed ipsam at. Doloremque quae expedita dolor earum alias consequuntur, quisquam ipsum et itaque doloribus!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla laudantium iusto, mollitia ut obcaecati omnis ullam enim natus. Optio
    commodi labore rerum possimus nesciunt, neque soluta, perferendis aliquam quia amet!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio ea possimus adipisci molestias, ellitia qui id veritatis quisquam animi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla saepe, consequuntur quidem iste, placeat vero quasi laborum ab voluptatibus repellendus reprehenderit itaque non quae quia, sed pariatur doloribus minus quo.
  </div>
</div>
```

why spanning or margin ? see the background-color covering the whole height and both columns scrolling together :

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}

.column-1 {
  /* grid-row: span 2;*/
  background: lightblue;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /*grid-row: span 1;*/
  /* margin-bottom:auto;*/
}
```

```html
<div id='grid'>
  <div class="column-1 sticky">
    Table of contents (How do I get this to stay in view while the user scrolls down to read the content in #column-2?)

  </div>
  <div class="column-1">
    Super long content Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, voluptate, id. Reprehenderit quae tempora totam, sed ipsam at. Doloremque quae expedita dolor earum alias consequuntur, quisquam ipsum et itaque doloribus!Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla laudantium iusto, mollitia ut obcaecati omnis ullam enim natus. Optio commodi labore rerum possimus nesciunt, neque soluta, perferendis aliquam quia amet!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, voluptate, id. Reprehenderit quae tempora totam, sed ipsam at. Doloremque quae expedita dolor earum alias consequuntur, quisquam ipsum et itaque doloribus!Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla laudantium iusto, mollitia ut obcaecati omnis ullam enim natus. Optio commodi labore rerum possimus nesciunt, neque soluta, perferendis aliquam quia amet!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Optio ea possimus adipisci molestias, e. Optio ea possimus adipisci molestias, excepturi fuga, dolore eius quibusdam ab natus in obcaecati, a quis. Harum nulla perferendis ipsam quidem, modi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Omnis eius recusandae, facere eaque veniam earum dolores accusamus atque sequi asperiores laboriosam aperiam eos reprehenderit moLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, voluptate, id. Reprehenderit quae tempora
    totam, sed ipsam at. Doloremque quae expedita dolor earum alias consequuntur, quisquam ipsum et itaque doloribus!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla laudantium iusto, mollitia ut obcaecati omnis ullam enim natus. Optio
    commodi labore rerum possimus nesciunt, neque soluta, perferendis aliquam quia amet!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio ea possimus adipisci molestias, ellitia qui id veritatis quisquam animi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla saepe, consequuntur quidem iste, placeat vero quasi laborum ab voluptatibus repellendus reprehenderit itaque non quae quia, sed pariatur doloribus minus quo.
  </div>
</div>
```

ressources

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ -/- https://gridbyexample.com/